# Eclipse FTP "Team Plugin"

Tags: eclipse, ftp

It seems to me from the following page
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-team/target.php
and other pages like it. that there has been a robust, mature, properly integrated (and seemingly very smart) way to upload and synchronize files from an eclipse workspace with an FTP site for four to six years already.
It seams from that page and similar pages around the web that "The WebDAV and FTP plugins are built as part of **the platform build**" which to me in plain english would mean that if you have the core eclipse files you should already have it.

This is obviously not the case. you dont even have the plugins required to make basic ftp access unless you install it from a repository.
Not only is it not installed. it is not available from the default plugin repositries set up when you download eclipse.

Not only that but I could not even find the link to the repository anywhere.
RSE - which seams like a library out of the nineties with such limited functionality that shell clients writen for windows 3.1 could do more in less steps - has its plugin repository url posted in many places. but the team plugin has only links to CVS repositories of the source at best. even most of those are broken.

In conclusion.
**Does anyone know how to install the "team" ftp client so that I can synchronize my content with FTP?**

Comment: "it seams to be the largest software ecosystem ever in history", I think that honour goes to emacs...

Comment: I think you're misreading the page. It's not claiming that end-user sync tools are included by default, only that the low-level OSGi plugins that provide the low-level functions are in there.

Comment: This should be on serverfault.com.

Comment: @Ether: No, only programmers would really care about this

Comment: @Glen: Emacs had more extentions, active extentions, or users that eclipse?

@Ether: What's "serverfault.com"? is that like a StackOverflow for System Admins? Why would they have answers about an IDE?

@bmargulies: the Team system seams to be a robust system for synching. If you just provide an FTP service, like the default CVS or the extensions for Subversion or the like, then you end up with the ultimate solution.
It Seams like the service existed back in 2004. the question is why did it get dumped?

Comment: Your question is similar to this one: [How to add FTP support to eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95800/how-to-add-ftp-support-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, time for me to answer my own question.

No RSE does not do what org.eclipse.team.ftp was able to accomplish five years ago. Somehow that functionality never made it in. I have no idea why they dropped a perfectly logical solution in favor of the new backwards methodology.

However, visiting the site that @bmargulies recommended I realized that Jcraft still hosts the original FTP and WebDav Service for Team Services (upon which their sftp service is built)

So you can just point your eclipse install dialog at  http://eclipse.jcraft.com/ and install the original plugin.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Well, [here](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/) is an sftp plugin on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

It is only about internal plugin defining a basic *container* for any ftp or webdav-based application.
You can see, when looking at:

- the source of [eclipse.ftp](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/platform-vcm-home/plugins/target/org.eclipse.ftp/src/org/eclipse/ftp/), that this is mainly an exception, some interfaces and a basic FTP container.
- the [sources of the target.ftp](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/platform-vcm-home/plugins/target/org.eclipse.target.ftp/src/org/eclipse/target/internal/ftp/) plugin, that that feature is here from more than 4 years, untouched, with basic functions only.

Only a more advance client like [eclipse.team.ftp](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.team.ftp/src/org/eclipse/team/internal/ftp/) defines a client, but not on eclipse.team.ftp no more, since this is now the [DSDP Target Management component](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Team_Development) which actually has developed a more advanced FTP/Webdav layer. It took over [since 2006](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html).

Comment: EXACTLY! Precisely!

"eclipse.team.ftp" seams to to define a normal client. but they gave way to the more backward RSE in 2006. The RSE workflow makes no sense for 90% of use cases. the Team system made 100%. yet for some reason, eclipse.team.ftp was dropped in favor of RSE and I want to know if there is any way to bring it back.

Comment: @Rabbi: I do not think so: RSE has taken over, and should include most of the features of team.ftp (plus a lot of features you might not care about)

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for this. Any solution for you yet?

This one also has been left dead and then excluded. :((
[Team Synchronization on top of RSE](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform/Team_Synchronization_on_top_of_RSE)

I guess there are still not enough Eclipse developers interested in it. Especially if one continue to see not only dead projects but even succesfull ftp-sync projects being shut out.

Really sad.