# How can I get autocomplete for CSS3 properties on Eclipse (Helios)

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, css

Please note that I already have CSS autocomplete support active, I need the CSS3 properties and other proprietary properties for CSS like border-raduis, ::selection, -mozkit and -webkit properties.

Comment: What's providing the autocomplete that you already have in place?

Comment: The default eclipse helios provides autocomplete for normal CSS properties. But the advanced CSS properties are not provided.

Answer (score 3):

You could install the [Aptana Studio 3.0.3 plugin](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) which has support for CSS3 properties. [Aptana Ticket #1986](https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1986) shows a way to enable matching for browser vendor specific extensions. [Ticket #1495](https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1495) is also relevant.

**WARNING!** I read on [How do I add FTP support to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95800/how-to-add-ftp-support-to-eclipse/3358358#3358358), that the plugin could *potentially* overwrite or re-organise a lot of your Eclipse workspace. This is an older answer now, so the new version of plugin might be better. I wouldn't want my advice to break your Eclipse without warning you first :-)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there an alternative for Aptana. I mean, can't we import some kind of autocomplete file with CSS3 properties into eclipse. Doesn't eclipse provide an infrastructure to provide autocomplete files?