# connect to website using eclipse/ develop-debug locally or not?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

So I've downloaded Eclipse because the consensus is that dreamweaver is lame. In dreamweaver I was used to just making a change and hitting ⌘+shift+u to upload my file to my site and see the change i made.

In eclipse, I can I connect to my website so that I can mimic this behavior? Is there a better way to do this? Should I be debugging locally using mamp or something, then transfer the files with fetch (again, or something) when I am done?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use FTP to upload stuff to your server? Do you use OS X?

Comment: I mean, I guess I would if eclipse doesn't have any functionality to upload to a server. Yes, I use Lion.

Comment: So what are you using? FTP? SCP? SSH?

Comment: @powtac He was using dreamweaver, which has integrated ftp functionality. It uploads for him. He wants to know if the same can be done in eclipse.

Comment: I also use ctrl + shift + u to upload in eclipse works like a charm

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95800/how-do-i-add-ftp-support-to-eclipse

Comment: Yes, it's a much better idea to develop and debug locally and then upload to your server once everything is working... unless you like taking your website down every time you forget a semicolon or something. It's even more important if you're working on a page that affects your site's security. But if you don't want to do that, just follow the instructions at powtac's link, above.

Comment: @powtac thanks for that link. there's a warning there. does aptana still ad loads of advertisements. is it better to use just aptana alone in your opinion?

Comment: You dont need to install aptana, there are several other FTP plugins available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install one of the available FTP plugins:

- http://www.wemakeapplejuice.be/2008/05/ftp-support-in-eclipse/
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#What_is_the_Target_Management_Project.3F
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/classftp/
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-team/target.php