# Web Development - Saving/Uploading files to Linux server from Windows

Tags: php, linux, project-management, text-editor, web-deployment

I will be developing a new project in PHP. The scripts will need to be tested on Linux and I will be coding on windows.  The script cant be tested on Windows because I will be running Asterisk server on Linux. The script I will write will communicate with the Asterisk server.  It will be uploading the files specific directories on Linux for testing. There are three directories I will be working on:

- `/var/www/`
- `/var/www/admin`
- `/user/local/bin/` -  Daemon (process) script will be written in PHP.

It will be annoying I have to keep uploading files to the specific directories via FTP client. So what is alternative good solution to upload files easily to Linux server while im coding on  Windows?

Comment: You could mount a remove directory as a network share, but then again you're pretty much just uploading via FTP like that as well. It's slightly more transparent though

Answer (score 0):

Investigate setting up an SMB share on the Linux machine that you can map as a network drive on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a `samba` server and mount the relevant directories as drives on your windows client.

As an alternative, you can use the deployment capabilites of your IDE

- [Eclipse PDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt)
  see also this answer [How do I add FTP support to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944100/1741542)
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone else comes across it....Use something like [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org) so that when you save your code your files will be automatically saved to the server