# How can I connect to a SFTP server using the "Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime" Eclipse plugin and a .pem private key?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sftp

I am trying to use Eclipse as a remote editor. The files I want to edit are on an SFTP server, which I usually connect to using a private [`.pem` key](https://serverfault.com/q/9708/126950) (it's an [OpenStack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack) node). Can I've read that Eclipse natively supports FTP and SSH through the [*Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime* Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944100/395857). How shall I configure it to connect to an SFTP using a private `.pem` key?

I don't have any password since I prove my identity using the private `.pem` key, so when I try to SSH into the server without entering any password:

[image]

It complains:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add your private key in the following configuration window:

[image]

You'll then be able to connect to the SFTP server (when ask leave the password blank or put any random password as the private key will be used to connect anyway) and remote edit in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth this works in Zend Studio as well when trying to use AWS