# Eclipse Git: use SFTP on push to master

Tags: eclipse, git, sftp, git-commit, git-push

- I am using **Eclispe IDE** ;
- We are using **Git (Bonobo Git)** on Windows server ;
- The global render of our project is on a distant **DEV server.**

**Every push to master branch on the git server**, we would like to **upload the updated files through `SFTP` on the DEV server.**

How can I setup an SFTP on local and upload only when I push to the master branch?

Should we do it this way:

> Local → [COMMIT & PUSH] → GIT server → **[SFTP]** → DEV server.

Or this way:

> Local → [COMMIT & PUSH] → GIT server.
>
> **If push**:
>
> Local →           **[SFTP]**          → DEV server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Eclipse IDE, you could set up an SSH connection to your DEV server. Eclispe has [built-in SSH connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304153/how-can-i-connect-to-a-sftp-server-using-the-remote-system-explorer-end-user-ru). You could then set up the SFTP port and upload your work by SFTP everytime you hit **save**.

Then, you could commit and push and your work will already be on the server.