# Eclipse send local edited files with Eclipse FTP

Tags: eclipse, ftp, eclipse-plugin

I'm really new with Eclipse. I'm a programmer and i have 2 site that i work on.
One is setup with a GIT.. so when i edit a file, i commit the change et the file is send to my server.

For the other site, i use Notepad ++, and when i edit my files, i use filezila to send it to the server..

My question, is, can i use Eclipse to edit the file and then send it via FTP ?

So i will not need Notepad++ and Filezilla anymore!

Here what i did: i create a new project (local), so i can edit the file in Eclipse. But to send it via FTP i see this topic [How do I add FTP support to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95800/how-do-i-add-ftp-support-to-eclipse)

and i created my connection with Remote System! And everythings works..

But the problem is, what i have to do to 'commit' or 'upload' my edited files ?
Because if y right click on my project, and i go hover de TEAM, only 2 options appears: Apply Patch, Share Project

There is no commit or send or upload...

What should I do?

Comment: Which option did you install into your Eclipse, RSE or Aptana? Also, what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hello! I install RSE, and i'm using the last version MARS 1. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RES works a little differently than the Team plugins. You have to use the RSE perspective and create a connection to your FTP server. Then you can interact with files through that connection (not through the Team menu).

See [this video](https://youtu.be/5ASxltuXKic?t=1m14s) for a demonstration; it's an older version but should be close enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I appreciate !