# Eclipse FTPS (SSL Explicit Encryption) Connection Using Remote Systems Explorer

Tags: eclipse, encryption, ftp, ftps, eclipse-rse

Is it possible to use Eclipse Remote Systems Explorer to establish an FTPS TLS/SSL Explicit Encryption connection?  I've worked with RSE before to create connections for both FTP and SFTP but I don't see any way to do FTPS.  Searching through other questions leads me to the Aptana plugin but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95800/how-do-i-add-ftp-support-to-eclipse), I may not want to venture down that path due to the warnings of excessive advertisements and messing up the Eclipse workspace.  I would like to stay with RSE if at all possible.