# Is there a modern open source text editor for IBM i stream files in the PASE environment

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-midrange, aix, ibm-ifs

Do you know of an open source Eclipse plugin text editor for use with text and source files in the IBM i  Pase / aix file system ? Ideally it would have an IBM i IFS browser and edit similar to the one in Rational Developer for i.

Comment: Er... you want an Eclipse-plugin that is a text-editor and runs on Aix?

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond Thanks for taking time to comment on this question. I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin that allows me to edit a text file which exists on an IBM i machine. The text file has been created from the PASE shell, so is in the AIX file system. Eclipse is running on my windows laptop. So to use the plugin I would expect to need to create a connection to the remote IBM i from within Eclipse. Hopefully my question makes more sense now. Let me know if you have any further questions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674945/4763757) from a similar SO question.

Other than that..

- Rational Developer for i does have an integrated IFS browser.
- [Notepad++ with NppFTP](https://ashkulz.github.io/NppFTP/) in SFTP mode seems to work okay for Windows.
- If you're interested in using Visual Studio code, a simple Google search for "Visual Studio Code sftp browser" will show you some extensions which allows you to access the IBM i IFS using SFTP as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I looked at the SO question, Aptana seemed promising but having difficulty in downloading a stand alone or eclipse plugin from their website. So now pursuing the Notepad++ route,

Comment: So far have found that plugin manager has been removed from the version I have. Latest version ( see comment on https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5-released.html ), hopefully it will be added  in later versions. I may try uninstalling and going back to an earlier version.

Comment: Many thanks @Lian Allan. Have found WinSCP ( https://winscp.net/eng/index.php )which seems very simple to install and connect. Am now exploring connection issues probably to do with the IBM i so may need to  come back to your suggestions.

Comment: @mike if the plugin manager is missing from npp, you're still able to install them manually :)

Comment: Thanks @Liam Allan, downloaded the plugin and placed it in the Notepad++ plugin folder and now can run Plugins>NppFTP

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not an eclipse plug-in, but [Orion](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion) is an browser based, open source project under the Eclipse Cloud Development top-level project.

And it's [supported on the IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Orion).